# Ajax and jQuery page reloading

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load

I have an issue to making a function - load page without reloading, I have an problem that is "I want to show alert when link is 404 or not net connection is lost". I know this code `jqXHR.status == 0` to get net connection error or `jqXHR.status !== 0` for 404 but I don't know I don't know how I implement this code with my existing code.

Please help me write this function.

```
$(function(){
    $("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){
      pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
      $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
        $('#containt').html(data);
      }});
      if(pageurl!=window.location){
        window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);  
      }
      return false;  
    });
  });
  $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    $.ajax({url:location.pathname+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
      $('#containt').html(data);
    }});
  });
```

```
<a rel="tab" href="./404.php">Show me 404 ALert Pls</a>
```

Comment: the error comes in error function of ajax where you can read xhr code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it this way using error function

```
    $.ajax({
        url: pageurl + '?rel=tab',
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            if(xhr.status == 0){
              alert('connect to internet');
              return false; }

            alert(xhr.status);
            // here you can use the xhr code to return to main page or whatever
            alert(thrownError);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#containt').html(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what happens when net connection not available?

Comment: xhr.status = 0 when no internet connection  you will only get other status when connection is active, because request cant be made without internet

Comment: i have added the offline check

Comment: Thank You so much

Comment: welcome. if it worked for you,you  can choose it as accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Add a callback for an "error" event or "statusCode".

```
$.ajax({
      url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',
      success: function(data){
        $('#containt').html(data);
      },
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    }
  }

});
```

From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

**error**

> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String
> errorThrown )
>
> A function to be called if the request fails. The
> function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x,
> XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that
> occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible
> values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error",
> "abort", and "parsererror". **When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown
> receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found"
> or "Internal Server Error."** (in HTTP/2 it may instead be an empty
> string) As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of
> functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is
> not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.
> This is an Ajax Event.

**statusCode (default: {})**

> Type: PlainObject An object of numeric HTTP codes and functions to be
> called when the response has the corresponding code. If the request is
> successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the
> success callback; if it results in an error (including 3xx redirect),
> they take the same parameters as the error callback.
>
> (version added: 1.5)

Comment: Thank You So Much